# Cannot serial write to an arduino using pyserial

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port, pyserial

I am trying to send either a 1 or a 0 to an arduino using the pyserial package. I have the arduino physically plugged into a USB port (COM6) and have it running the following block of code to turn on or off a light in response to the input.

```
#define LED_PIN 12

void setup()
{
  // Set up serial communication at 9600 baud
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    char cmd = Serial.read();
    if (cmd == '1') {
      digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);
      Serial.println("LED turned on!");
    }
    else if (cmd == '0') {
      digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
      Serial.println("LED turned off!");
    }
  }
}
```

However, the line in my python code `ser = serial.Serial("COM6", 9600)` is producing the error message: `serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM6': PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied.', None, 5)`. I have tried making sure all programs that could be accessing the serial port are closed (including the arduino IDE) and updating and restarting my PC. The strange thing is that both pieces of code work fine on a friends computer, and the arduino is able to take serial commands. Does anyone have further trouble shooting suggestions?

Below is all the python code if it is any use, we are trying to set up a UI using flask. Thanks in advance to anyone with the patience to help out this beginner : )

```
import numpy
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, redirect
from functools import wraps
import pymongo
import serial



app = Flask(__name__)

#set up secret.key
app.secret_key = ...

#Database
client = pymongo.MongoClient(...)
db = client.user_login_system

# Decorators, decide whether or not to allow user go to specific pages
def login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*arg, **kwargs):
        #checks if user is logged in
        if 'logged_in' in session:
            #if yes, it renders the dashboard templates
            return f(*arg, **kwargs)
        else:
            #if not, it redirects to the home pahe
            return redirect('/')
        
    return wrap

#We need to import our routes as well in this file
from user import routes

#create route
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

#best rout to assure that assure lands on that page
@app.route('/dashboard/')

#checks if user is logged in before even allowing access to dashboard
@login_required

def dashbaord():
    # Render the dashboard template with the current LED status
    return render_template("dashboard.html", status='OFF')

#create file to automatically execute flask
#set up two templates one for Home page and another for dashboard page
#arduino stuff (V1)
ser = serial.Serial("COM6", 9600)

# Define route for turning LED on
@app.route('/turn_on/')
def turn_on():
    ser.write(b'1')  # Send "1" to Arduino to turn on LED
    #return 'LED turned on!'
    return render_template("dashboard.html", status="LED is oN")

# Define route for turning LED off
@app.route('/turn_off/')
def turn_off():
    ser.write(b'0')  # Send "0" to Arduino to turn off LED
    #return 'LED turned off!'
    return render_template("dashboard.html", status="LED is off")
```

Comment: BTW: if the Port is correct but used by another app, I get `serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM4': PermissionError(13, 'Zugriff verweigert', None, 5)` (Which translates to 'Access denied' )
If it's the wrong name the error is `serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM6': FileNotFoundError`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to give it the right permission?
Try run this code as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Doublecheck the correct port name

```
from serial import Serial
import serial.tools.list_ports as ports

def test():
   print('List Of Available Serial Ports')
   for p in (ports.comports(False)):
       print (p)
   print('_'*40)
   s = Serial('COM6')
   print(s.name, s.baudrate, end='')
   if s.is_open :
      print(' open')
   else :
      print(' closed')
```